# What do Attributes of Maven plugins mean (jacoco:report-aggregate)

Tags: maven, jacoco-maven-plugin

Example 1:
[jacoco:report-aggregate](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-aggregate-mojo.html) says:

```
Attributes:
* Requires a Maven project to be executed.
```

I've stumbled trying to use the "report-aggregate" goal, as it works only if unit tests are executed by the same command as JaCoCo plugin itself;
in other words, if I use command-line to run unit tests from module A, then I execute another command to run unit tests from module B, then I execute yet another command in special module C (created just to run jacoco aggregation) to trigger `jacoco:report-aggregate` - *it won't work*, JaCoCo will generate an empty aggregated report. In another case, it won't be empty, but the aggregated coverage will be 0%. It works only if unit test are executed by same command.

Thus the question, what exactly does "*Requires a Maven project to be executed*" mean?
(The described behavior is probably just a peculiarity of jacoco, but still I would never write the word sequence "Requires a Maven project to be executed" -- a project is a project, it can be code or it can be a declaration, it is not a command, thus it cannot be executed - plain non-sense to me)

Comment: That requirement just means that you need a maven project, described by a `pom.xml`, to run the specific goal. Otherwise you would get an error like so; `Goal requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (...). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory`. My guess is that something else is going wrong in your setup/expectation on how this plugin works.